# Property of points in the plane where distances are pairwise different. Existence of a pair which has min/max distance in different subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I was trying some exercises to prepare for a graph theory exam and I am stuck on a particular problem, namely:

One must show that given $P$, a set of $N$ points in the plane such that all distances are pairwise different, there is an $N$ such that one can find distinct points $x,y$ and subsets $S,S′$ of $P$, both of size $7$, where $x,y$ are in $S\cap S′$ and $d(x,y)$ is maximal in $S$ and minimal in $S′$. Additionally show that $N$ can be chosen to be less than $2020$.

I know that somehow I can apply results of Ramsey theory, my problem is I can't seem to translate the points to the right graph I need to consider.

Comment: $S$ consists of $x,y$ and five other points.  The other five points are roughly between $x$ and $y$.  $S'$ also consists of $x,y$ and five other points, with the other points different from the ones in $S$.  The other points n $S'$ are far apart and far from $x,y$.  We have mentioned twelve points, so you should be able to find a $P$ of that size.  The hard part is showing that for any $P$ of that size you can find $S,S'$.  I am not sure twelve is the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm pretty confident there are some simple constructions of sets of size 12 which do not have this property. For example take $2$ parallel lines put $6$ points on each line with pairwise different distances s.t. each distance is smaller than the distance between the lines. Since $S$ has size $7$, S has points on each line therefore $x,y$ must be on opposite lines to be maximal in one of the subsets, but then obviously they can't be minimal in the other subset since there is always pairs of points on a line in any given subset of size $7$.

Comment: I was suggesting the construction to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Ahh I see what you meant, I tried something in this direction but got stuck unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the $7$-set of minimum diameter and let $x,y$ its two points at maximum distance.

Now consider the set of vertices that are at distance at least $d(x,y)$ from $x$ and $y$. There has to be a bunch of them, because there can't be too many points in the the union of the two balls of radius $d(x,y)$ with centers $x,y$. You'll get a constant number $c$ such that at most $c$ points are at distance less than $d(x,y)$ from at least one of $x$ and $y$.

Consider the graph on these at least $N-c$ points that are at distance more than $d(x,y)$ from both $x$ and $y$.  We color an edge blue if the distance is less than $d(x,y)$ and red if it is more than $d(x,y)$. this graph cannot have a blue $K_7$. If it has a red $K_5$ then we can take those $5$ points and $x,y$ to form the set $S'$.

Hence if $N$ is at least $R(5,7)+c$ we can guarantee those two numbers. It seems that $R(5,7) \leq 143$.

---

Here is a cheap way to get a $c$: we cover the union of the two open balls of radius $d(x,y)$ and centers $(0,0)$ and $(0,d(x,y))$ using the open balls of radius $d(x,y)/2$ and centers $(id(x,y)/4/4,kd(x,y)/4)$ with $0\leq i,j \leq 8$. So none of these balls can have more than $6$ points, hence there can be at most $9^2\cdot 6=486$ points in the union of those two open balls.

So it seems like $486+143 = 629$ works.

Comment: Ohh this is great thanks. Just so I know I understood the argument correctly a blue $K_7$ is not possibly since we chose the $7$-set of minimum diameter. Why exactly can't there be too many points in the balls around $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I think I gave an argument that works. The idea is just that those balls have radius $d(x,y)$ so if there's a ton of points in there there is going to be a $7$-set with smaller diameter. I think I gave a value that works.

Comment: Of course this makes sense to me, thank you so much :) I was a little stumped by the exercise but I think I learned some things along the way.

Comment: My pleasure glad to help

Comment: I believe this is the intended solution, but I didn't think of Ramsey theory.

Comment: Oh indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As another approach, take $S$ to be the set of $7$ points with minimum diameter.  There may be more than one, but the diameter and the points $x,y$ at the ends of that diameter are fixed.  Construct a regular hexagon with diameter $\overline{xy}$ and tile the plane with hexagons of that size.  No hexagon except the first one can contain more than six points or that set of seven would have smaller diameter than $d(x,y)$.  Each point can only be within $d(x,y)$ of points within seven hexagons.  If we have points in $36$ hexagons besides the first we can find five of them at mutual distances greater than $d(x,y)$ and farther than $d(x,y)$ from each of $x,y$.  We eliminate the first hexagon and all that surround it, then pick any point, eliminate its hexagon and all that surround it, and keep going.  We need $7+6 \cdot 35 +1=212$ points to guarantee we can carry out the construction.

Comment: This is also a very nice solution, thank you for the insight.